# Groovy Grails handle controller parameters

Tags: grails, parameters, controller

I do an AJAX request from mt front-end with array as parameter. Example of the array:

```
arr = [13, 56, 43]
```

When in Grails controller I print params I get `arr[]:[13, 56, 43]`.
However, when in front-end array consists of only one element (`arr = [25]`, for instance), then in controller I get `arr[]:32`. However, I need the parameter to be the list, like `arr[]:[32]`. How can I do that?

Comment: This do the trick `List<String> myParam = params.list('myParams')` instead of asking if the param is instance of list or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the controller you can use

```
params.list('arr[]')
```

This will always return a list, with zero, one or more than one element, unlike the basic

```
params.'arr[]'
```

which gives you `null` if there are no `arr[]` parameter values, the single value if there is one, and a list if there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

I think In the controller you can use

```
List arr = []

arr = params.list
```

or

```
def arr
arr = params.list as List
```